# In Forth, how many characters does 'expect' read?

Tags: forth

The [Forth-83 spec](http://forth.sourceforge.net/standard/fst83/fst83-12.htm#expect) defines the word `expect` as follows:

```
      EXPECT       addr +n --                    M,83                 
           Receive characters and store each into memory.  The transfer
           begins at addr proceeding towards higher addresses one byte
           per character until either a "return" is received or until
           +n characters have been transferred.  No more than +n
           characters will be stored.  The "return" is not stored into
           memory.  No characters are received or transferred if +n is
           zero.  All characters actually received and stored into
           memory will be displayed, with the "return" displaying as a
           space.
```

So, it reads up to, but not including, a RETURN or EOL.

But without a terminator, and without returning the number of characters read, how do I know where the string ends?

Leo Brodie refers to a word `accept`, which does something very similar, which has the signature `( addr +n -- +m )`. That does return the number of characters read, which is what I'd expect. But that's not in the spec...

Comment: If the memory pointed to by `addr` has been cleared to contain all zeroes, then finding the length of the string afterwards is a matter of finding the first remaining zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard](http://forth.sourceforge.net/standard/fst83/fst83-12.htm#span) also defines `SPAN`, which tells you the number of characters read.

Also note, that in the new standard this function is obsolete, use `ACCEPT` instead.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the wrong spec. The ANS spec is much better designed (although nigh incomprehensible).